# Angular 4: test if window.location.href has been called

Tags: angular, testing

I have an `AuthGuard` service responsible for detecting if a user is logged in. If not logged in, I redirect the user to our oauth provider url.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { Session } from './../core/security/session.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  /**
   * Class constructor.
   * @constructor
   *
   * @param {Session} - Instance of session.
   */
  constructor(private session: Session) {}

  /**
   * Method to implements from CanActivate interface.
   * Check if a user is authenticated.
   *
   * @return {boolean}
   */
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.session.isActive()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.redirectToProvider();
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Redirect to Identity unauthorized url.
   */
  private redirectToProvider() {
    const unauthorizeUrl = environment.api.identity.unauthorizeUrl;
    window.location.href = unauthorizeUrl;
  }
}
```

I would like to know if `window.location.href` has been called when a Session does not exists. Here is what I did so far:

```js
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { Session } from './../core/security/session.service';

describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        Session
      ],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    });
  });

  describe('.canActivate', () => {
    describe('active session', () => {
      it('returns true',
        async(inject([AuthGuard, Session], (guard, session) => {
          session.set({ name: 'user' });

          expect(guard.canActivate()).toBeTruthy();
        })
      ));
    });

    describe('no session', () => {
      it('redirects the user',
        async(inject([AuthGuard, Session], (guard, session) => {
          spyOn(window.location, 'href');
          session.destroy();

          expect(guard.canActivate()).toBeFalsy();
          expect(window.location.href).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
      ));
    });
  })
});
```

but it gives me the following error:

```js
Failed: <spyOn> : href is not declared writable or has no setter
```

Is there a way to mock the window object to achieve this or do I need to rely on some special class to handle such redirection so I can inject them in test?

Comment: Why not use this.router.navigate or this.router.navigateByUrl instead of window.location.href

Comment: I've tried but `this.router.navigateByUrl` seems to only work with Angular registered routes. However, in my case I'm trying to redirect to an external url.

Answer (score 8):

You can inject `window` as an injection token. Angular also has a `DOCUMENT` DI token in @angular/common that you can directly use with `document.location.href`.

```js
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const WindowToken = new InjectionToken('Window');
export function windowProvider() { return window; }
```

Add it in `app.module.ts`:

```js
providers: [
    ...
    { provide: WindowToken, useFactory: windowProvider }
  ]
```

And inject it in the service:

```js
constructor(@Inject(WindowToken) private window: Window, private session: Session)
```

In your spec file, mock the window object and test it. I've created a working example with two test services (one dependent on the other). The service is created with Angular's Static Injector:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CustomHrefService } from './custom-href.service';
import {AppModule} from '../app.module';
import {WindowToken} from './window';
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomHref2Service} from './custom-href-2.service';

const MockWindow = {
  location: {
    _href: '',
    set href(url: string) {
      this._href = url;
    },
    get href() {
      return this._href;
    }
  }
};

describe('CustomHrefService', () => {
  let service: CustomHrefService;
  let setHrefSpy: jasmine.Spy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    setHrefSpy = spyOnProperty(MockWindow.location, 'href', 'set');

    const injector = Injector.create({
      providers: [
        { provide: CustomHrefService, useClass: CustomHrefService, deps: [WindowToken, CustomHref2Service]},
        { provide: CustomHref2Service, useClass: CustomHref2Service, deps: []},
        { provide: WindowToken, useValue: MockWindow}
      ]
    });
    service = injector.get(CustomHrefService);
  });

  it('should be registered on the AppModule', () => {
    service = TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [AppModule] }).get(CustomHrefService);
    expect(service).toEqual(jasmine.any(CustomHrefService));
  });

  describe('#jumpTo', () => {
    it('should modify window.location.href', () => {
      const url = 'http://www.google.com';
      service.jumpTo(url);
      expect(setHrefSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Editing the code to satisfy a test is not desired. Quite a lot of changes for a simple piece of code.

Comment: @CularBytes The code above is not a hack, it's a good practice. It's recommended to avoid directly referencing global objects in case your application is used in other environments (ie. Angular Universal). Unlike Jest which uses virtual DOM, Karma tests in the browser and it is not possible to directly stub or mock the window object. In any case, I don't believe the situation OP described is a very common test case unless you are aiming for 100% coverage - there are ways to avoid testing this.

Comment: exactly what I needed, I added  `replace(url) {this.href = url; }`, to fake also replace

Comment: If you only need to test the location change, I found creating a locationToken to be less likely to have side effects if the real window or document is still needed: https://indepth.dev/tree-shakable-dependencies-in-angular-projects/